# Remove postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-12.04

I want to remove postgresql-9.1 from Ubuntu 12.04

I use `apt-get remove --purge postgresql-9.1`

And I get error `* Use of uninitialized value $info{"pgdata"} in -d at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 331.`

I correctly set `PGDATA="/var/lib/postgresql/data"` in `/etc/environment`

Other actions, as `pg_ctl stop` or `service postgresql stop` make the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this on your command line:

```
export PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Then try the remove again.  You might want to play around with different -f -m combinations to 'ignore' the error.

```
apt-get remove -f -m --purge postgresql-9.1
```

Or, you could, as root, just remove the files.  First, make sure no postgres stuff is running (ps -ax | grep post).  On my system I would:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/postgresql/data
rm -rf /usr/local/pgsql
```

(Careful with those rm -rf commands :-) )

The other thing that would need cleanup would be the startup and library stuff: Try:

ls /etc/*/*postgr*

if you see files like this:

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql             /etc/rc2.d/S20postgresql
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/postgresql.conf  /etc/rc3.d/S20postgresql
/etc/profile.d/postgres_path.sh    /etc/rc4.d/S20postgresql
/etc/rc0.d/K20postgresql           /etc/rc5.d/S20postgresql
/etc/rc1.d/K20postgresql           /etc/rc6.d/K20postgresql
```

then the next step would be to just rm them:

```
rm -f /etc/*/*postgr*
```

The aptitude management of packages is pretty handy.  I haven't ever used it to remove packages, I always worry if that will really work right.  Good luck.